# What did the Borg Queen mean when she told Harry "We'll see you soon" in Unimatrix Zero?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

In the Voyager episode, "Unimatrix Zero," the Borg Queen contacts Voyager and warns Janeway not to interfere in her attempts to root out and destroy Unimatrix Zero.  As the communication was ending, she told Harry Kim:

> "We'll see you soon, Harry"

**What did she mean by this?**  Was it ever followed up on in the series or books?

Comment: Psychological warfare can be a very powerful weapon.

Comment: Not knowing this was the name of a Voyager episode, I imagined going into this that it was some sort of crossover fanfiction between The Matrix, Star Trek, and Harry Potter.  I am slightly disappointed this did not turn out to be the case.

Comment: @Zibbobz - http://i.stack.imgur.com/ikcxV.jpg

Comment: Does anyone else think she said it just to screw with his head?

Comment: I always took it as an underhanded threat to assimilate the entire crew of Voyager.  Harry was the "everyman" member of the senior staff so the Queen threatening him personally was her twisted way of threatening the entire crew.  Also the Borg view everyone as drones that are part of a collective so a threat against one crew member is meant as a threat against all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just looked into this for you, and it doesn't look like there was any follow-up. If there was, it is considered unimportant enough to not be mention on *Wikipedia*, *Memory Alpha*, or *Memory Beta*. That's not conclusive, but I doubt you'll find anything more substantial.

It was likely a throw-away line that the creators wanted to get back to at some point - say, by having Harry assimilated or develop a relationship with the Borg Queen - but either forgot about or elected not to pursue. Such things happen with some regularity on television.

Comment: Yea, all I found was one thread on a forum somewhere else that people gave the opinion she was just yanking Harry's chain.  Just watched the episode and found it odd nothing came of it that I could find.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time a story just fizzled out on *Star Trek*. The *Conspiracy* storyline in *TNG* springs to mind.

Comment: All too true, sadly.  Though the bad special effects in Conspiracy made me glad it wasn't ever followed up on.

Comment: IIRC that *The Conspiracy* storyline was meant to be associated with the Borg. So it just got changed/dropped/adjusted later on. They couldn't change the old episode for obvious reason, so they "forgot" about it.

Comment: I always read it as a dig against Janeway. If you come at me, I'll come at you and yours.

Comment: @Mario: I believe the insectoid parasites in that episode were deemed too "mature" and "dark" for *TNG* (Roddenberry's words) and so were replaced by the Borg.

Comment: Yes, possible. Think that's possibly true. Didn't remember the specific reason they've had.

Comment: It's what *Memory Alpha* thinks, so it's the official reason at least. Whether it's an honest one or not is another question.

Comment: @JamesSheridan considering Roddenberry disliked the idea of the utopian federation having a coup, which is why the parasites were written in last minute, I doubt that's the reason. The original intention was for something like Section 31 to be the villain, corrupting the federation from the inside.

Answer (score 14):

Garrett Wang, the actor that played Harry Kim, has recently confirmed that he has **no idea** why the Borg Queen said that she'd see him soon.

From [Twitter](https://twitter.com/elroja65/status/490206747983101952):

> **@elroja65 :** Garrett do you know what the borg queen meant when she
>   said "**We'll see you soon, Harry**"  in Unimatrix?
>
> **@GarrettRWang :** Other than that being super creepy? no, I have no idea
>   what the Borg Queen was referring to lol

In the absence of a canon confirmation, I can offer some possible alternatives;

- It was a plotline that never got followed through.
- **It was a threat against Janeway** (e.g. knowing how protective of him she was)
- It was a threat against the crew in general
- It was intended to shake him up personally

I veer toward the second option. Janeway is attacking the Borg on a very personal level and despite her somewhat cold demeanour, it's clear that the Borg Queen views the whole unimatrix fiasco as an attempt to damage the collective and lessen their perfection.

She's saying, "*If you come at me and mine, I'll come at you and yours*".

Answer (score 5):

I was talking with Garrett Wang on Twitter about this and he still had no answer, BUT my two theories he liked a lot.

My two theories are:

1. That the Harry Kim the queen was talking to was the Kim that crossed over from a parallel universe. Therefore his biometric readings would show that his atomic structure vibrate on a different level. This means that he could hold the means of being able to crossover from one dimension to another. A trick I'm sure the Borg would love to get their hands on.
2. In the future Harry Kim become captain of the USS Rhode Island. During his adventures as captain it's entirely possible that Captain Kim and his crew traveled back and forth in time and maybe even battled the Borg and the Queen herself sometime in the past. A past from before Voyager. Then, during Voyagers journey in the Delta Quadrant, the Queen sees a young Harry Kim and says, "I'll be seeing you soon, Harry Kim." thus alluding to her knowledge of his future.

In fact I'm having a blog discussion about the Importance of Harry Kim in order to see if we can figure it out ourselves: http://murcray.blogspot.com/2014/08/importance-of-harry-kim.html